# Is there any reason why this code wouldnt work at the start of of some Python code?

Tags: python

This code is at the start and when I run the code it doesn't do anything and nothing shows up, please help?

```
users = {}
status = ""

def register():
    username = input("Please input the first 2 letters of your first name and your birth year ")
    password = input("Please input your desired password ")
    file = open("accountfile.txt","a")  
    file.write(username)   
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(password)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    if login():
        print("You are now logged in...")
    else:
        print("You aren't logged in!")

def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username")
    password = input("Please enter your password")  
    for line in open("accountfile.txt","r").readlines(): 
        login_info = line.split() 
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            return True
    print("Incorrect credentials.")
    return False
```

I expect the output to be a login system that then leads to a quiz but when I run it all I get is blank space

Comment: You are not invoking any function. Unless you're not sharing all your code.

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is creating a couple of variables and declaring some functions.

Neither of those things will result in any output. If you want the functions to run, you'll actually need to *call* them from somewhere, such as by putting `register()` or `login()` (with no indentation) after the function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the functions, but didn't call either, you should call one or both at the end of your script like :

```
def login():
    username = input("Please enter your username")
    password = input("Please enter your password")
    for line in open("accountfile.txt","r").readlines(): 
        login_info = line.split() 
        if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            return True
    print("Incorrect credentials.")
    return False

login()
```

Comment: Hhhhhhhh it doesn't matter, I'm just showing him that the issue is him not calling the function :p

Comment: Readability matters quite a bit. You aren't writing code for yourself here.

Comment: Changing `input` to `raw_input` is the wrong thing to do if this is running under Python 3 (which you should increasingly assume is the case unless otherwise specified).